# Python Submodule is not getting imported

Tags: python, eclipse, python-import, pydev

This is the file path for my Pydev project in Eclipse:

```
project
   |
   +----tests
   |      |
   |      +----subtests
   |      |       |
   |      |       +----__init__.py
   |      |       |
   |      |       +----test1.py
   |      |
   |      +----__init__.py
   |      |
   |      +----test2.py      
   |              
   +----mods
         |
         +----__init__.py
         |
         +----submods1
                 |
                 +----__init__.py
                 |
                 +----submods2
                         |
                         +----__init__.py
                         |
                         +----a.py
                         |
                         +----b.py
                         |
                        ...
                         |
                         +----z.py
```

test1 and test2 are exactly the same, all of the init files only have comments in them. The tests are getting the modules from the mods directory and those modules dependencies. When I run test1, all of the modules are found, but test2 always unable to find the same module (let's call it "z.py") in submods2. But somehow it's able to find the rest of the modules. It's not that it's unable to import something in z.py, it just cannot find the file at all.

test2:

```
>>> from mods.submod1.submod2 import z
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name z
>>> from mods.submod1 import submod2
>>> hasattr(submod2, 'z')
False
```

The only difference in the `sys.path` during the two tests are the directories that tests are located in,  `project/tests/subtests` for test1 and `project/tests` for test2.

I cannot figure out why test2 is unable to import z.py but test1 can and test2 can import the rest of the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my solution to this. In my `Run Configurations` for test2, the `Working directory` in the `Arguments` tab had a custom path `${workspace_loc:project/tests/}`, I switched it to the default path `${project_loc:/selected project name}` and that seems to be fixing the issue. While I don't understand how this fixed the problem, the result is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

To help diagnose the issue, do:

from mods.submod1 import submod2
print(submod2)

My guess is that it's not the module you're expecting.

What Python version are you using?

Comment: It's printing out `<module 'mods.submod1.submod2' from '..\mods\submod1\submod2\__init__.py'>` and I'm using Python 2.7.2 (can't change it as this is done by my job)